# Realm on iOS throws "Invalid value '301' for property'code'" where 'code' is of type Int

Tags: ios, json, realm

`code` is an integer, so it's declared as an `Int` in my subclass.swift file. The subclass is in the same format as the JSON, to enable saving the JSON directly to Realm.

I get this JSON:

```
...
"code": 301
...
```

And this is how I'm saving it:

```
realm.create(Student.self, value: jsonStudent, update: true)
```

But Realm throws this:

```
failed: caught "RLMException", "Invalid value '301' for property 'code'"
```

At first I thought the '301' might be getting parsed as a string, but that was not the case, calling 'dynamicType' on it in the debugger returns `NSCFNumber`, which is expected.

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's complaining about the data type? Is there some reason 301 might be an invalid integer value here?

Comment: @MikeTaverne Yes, it sees 301 as a double. Weirdly, this does not happen with other integers at other places other than "code".

Comment: Are there more instances of "code" in your JSON? If so, do any of them contain decimal values?

Comment: @MikeTaverne Yes, at least five more. All of them are integers.

Comment: Is there any resolution to this? I'm having the sam error with '120'

Answer (score 0):

`NSJSONSerialization` will convert `{"code": 301}` to an `NSNumber` of type `q`, which is integer. So the fact that you're getting an invalid property implies that the `code` property on your Realm model is of a different type (maybe `Float` or `Double`)?

Could you share your model definition here?

If your `code` property is actually `Int` or a variation thereof (`Int32`, `Int64`, etc.), this would imply there's a bug in Realm and I'd recommend that you open an issue at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues.